# in maya, set custom attributes of an expression node by variables

Tags: variables, attributes, expression, nodes, maya

I want to drive the ouput values of custom attributes of a expression node by variables inside this same expression node.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Expressions do not work like this. You cannot assing a value to an attribute this way. The direct assingment only works if you set an value of a connected destination. If you want to set an attribute, you have to use `setAttr()`.

Comment: the inputs can not be named, because the node will change of name after a import or a duplication of the node graph.

Comment: If you can describe a bit more in detail what you want to do with this expression it could be more clear if this works with expressions at all. Or maybe together with some script jobs which reconnect expressions in certain cases.

Comment: in fact, I just need to keep the same behavior whatever the scene where is the node graph. the probleme is the expression points to nodes with a specific names, but if I write a name for the input and the output of the expression it will not be able to work in reference, and if it is duplicated.

Comment: I fear you have to work with some scripts which do the correct connections and expression setup after a scene open event or a load reference event.

Comment: I will try this way. thank you a lot for you help.